# htaccess rewriterule to forward specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a help here with .htaccess regular expressions. I want to forward this url: `www.aloha.com/foo/bar/sample.html` to `www/aloha/foo/bar/index.php?go=sample`.

I tried to use

> RewriteRule /foo/bar/^(.*)?.html /foo/bar/index.php?go=$1 [L]

but it doesn't work.

I also already have another rewrite rule that clash with this rule. That's why I need to create another rule for this specific folder.

> RewriteRule ^(.*)?.html index.php?input=$1 [L]

Comment: Try removing the initial slash off both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/(.*?)\.html$ /foo/bar/index.php?go=$1 [L]
```

Some of your syntax was out of place. For example, the `^` denotes the beginning or a negation of a character class. Also, I'm assuming you want a file name, so don't use the optional capture `?`.

Finally, I made the capture non-greedy. I'd encourage you to take this a step further and be more specific with your capture.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/([^/]+)\.html$ /foo/bar/index.php?go=$1 [L]
```